# Save file with relative path from javabean or servlet

Tags: java, servlets, web, javabeans, relative-path

I need to save file from javabean or servlet, and I'm having trouble finding relative path, I tried:

(from servlet)

```
ServletContext servCont = this.getServletContext();
String contextPath = servCont.getRealPath(File.separator);
System.out.println("REAL PATH: "+ contextPath);
```

this gives me:

```
REAL PATH: E:\Web\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Saloni\
```

and project folder is:

```
E:\Web\Saloni
```

and from bean (bean is called Salon)

```
String path = Salon.class.getResource("Salon.class").getPath();
```

and got basically the same thing

```
/E:/Web/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Saloni/WEB-INF/classes/beans/Salon.class
```

If I just put file name into FileOutputStream file gets saved in eclipse workspace.

I read somewhere that I'm supposed to get to WEB-INF somehow but can't do that ..

Comment: I find this question unclear.  Where do you want to save this file?  Can you list the absolute path?

Comment: Are you trying to update a war file like this? **Relative** to what?

Comment: it just needs to be inside project, so when I transfer it to other machine it works,
it is just serialization of some objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Base path of the working directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043857/find-base-path-of-the-working-directory-in-java)