# Find Base path of the working directory in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Luna RCP. In the code of my plugin, I want the path of my workspace. I have used the following code:

```
String basePath = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

This should give:

```
/home/esghsni/avroWorkspace/AvroDesigner
```

But it is give incorrect path which include path the directory where eclipse rcp is stored.

I have checked all the related questions but none helped. I have also tried decoding the path returned (using `URLDecoder()`), but it gave some other path altogether.
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();

Comment: You mentioned working directory in the title, but used workspace in the question. You are looking for workspace of the eclipse instance where your plugin is installed. Right? In that case my earlier comment should help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: +1 . You can always check where you are by using `File f = new File("."); System.out.println(f.getPath());` This is created differently based on the path settings of `user.dir` setting for eclipse. This will produce a different output when running from command line, without eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

Use this file object `f` to get absolute path of `this` class.

Answer (score 0):

In an Eclipse plugin use:

```
IPath path = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation();
```

to get the full path of the workspace in file system.

Note: this must be run in a plugin, it won't work in a plain Java program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but the result is the path where my Eclipse RCP is stored (my desktop) and not my workspace folder...

Comment: What exactly do you want this folder for? It may not exist when you install your plugin in some other instance of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes previous answer is correct

```java
import java.io.File;

public class B {
    
    public static void main (String [] arr)

    {
    B b=new B();
    File f = new File(b.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    System.out.print(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers!
I just executed the same code on my friend's laptop and it gave the correct workspace path. So basically, the code:

String basePath = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

is working correctly. Seems as if there is some issues in my laptop or eclipse.

I also found out that when I switch the eclipse workspace and restart the eclipse, it gives me the correct workspace path (only once). But next executions onwards, it start giving me wrong output.